# Correct strong induction proof for series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have a series like this:

$$c_0 = 1, \quad c_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}c_i.$$

Here are the first few elements:
\begin{align*}
c_0 &= 1, &
c_1 &= 1, &
c_2 &= 2, \\
c_3 &= 4, &
c_4 &= 8, &
c_5 &= 16, \\
&\ \cdots.
\end{align*}

So, I guess that $n \ge 1 \iff c_n = 2^{n-1}$ and my proof is:

\begin{align*}
c_1 &= \sum_{i = 0}^{1-1}c_i\ = 1 = 2^0, \\
c_n &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}c_i + c_0.
\end{align*}

And now, assuming that $c_k = 2^{k-1} \iff 1 \le k < n$,

$$c_n = c_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}c_i + c_0 = 2^0 + 2^1 + \cdots +2^{n-2} + c_0 = (2^{n-1} - 1) + c_o = 2^{n-1}.$$

Is it ok?

Comment: Do you really need strong induction for this? Hint $c_{n+1}=c_{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_{i}$.

Comment: You use $\Leftrightarrow$ in strange ways.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but you still need to prove that $2^0+\dots+2^{n-2} = 2^{n-1}$.

Try this instead:

$$c_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i = \hskip-1cm \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n-\color{red}{2}} c_i}_{=c_{n-1} \text{, by the definition}} \hskip-1cm + c_{n-1} = c_{n-1} + c_{n-1} = 2 \hskip-13mm \underbrace{c_{n-1}}_{=2^{n-2} \text{, by the induction hyp.}} \hskip-15mm = 2 \cdot 2^{n-2} = 2^{n-1}.$$